# JQuery strange attribute

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom

I have a piece of code that uses a strange selector that I haven't been able to identify:

```
$("div[tag=" + someVariable + "]").css("display", "block");
```

As far as I'm undestanding it, the selector looks for a `div` element with an attribute called `tag`, whose value is equal to `someVariable`.

What is the `tag` attribute? Lots of Googling gave me no indication.

EDIT: The following line is:

```
$("div[tag=" + someVariable+ "]").addClass("someClass");
```

Could it be that that this code creates a `div` with a custom attribute, then adds it to the page?

Comment: Your 2nd question is absolutely irrelevant with the 1st one. It could be anything.

Comment: To your second question. If you can finde something like `$('body').append("<div tag='" + someVariable + "'></div>");` than may yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though not consistent with the HTML spec, most browsers place no restrictions on custom-defined attributes.

Whoever created this has HTML that looks like:

```
<div tag="something">
```

HTML5, <strike>though not officially released</strike> (HTML5.0 reached "recommendation" status in Oct of 2014), supports the concept of custom tags by pre-pending them with "data-" ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)). So, technically, it really should have been written as:

```
<div data-tag="something">
```

and

```
$("div[data-tag=" + someVariable + "]")
```

Comment: Please see the edits above. There is no `div` in the HTML with the custom attribute being used. It seems as if the custom attribute is added to the `div` tag, then it is added to the page. Does that seem correct?

Comment: But JDB means that it used to be `data-tag` but someone just typed `tag` so actually its wrong but it still works since there is no MUST to add it like that

Comment: @user111222333 - If there is no HTML element with the `tag` attribute, then the selector will fail and no elements will be selected.

Comment: @JDB I know its nitpicking, but `fail` would be the wrong word; `return nothing`, but not `fail`. Otherwise totally agree.

Comment: True... "fail" gives the impression that an error would be generated, though one could argue that it would "fail" to return any elements. Regardless, the result would be an empty jQuery object, so the `css` and `addClass` functions would have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any name for your attributes, you can even call them `somereallystrangename` - though it's not advised and will not pass any validation. The consensus is to use `data-{tag}` as an attribute that you defined yourself. but there is nothing stopping you (or the people who wrote your script) from using `tag` as an attribute name. `Tag` is not an officially used tag in HTML, though.

Comment: So it's a custom attribute?

Comment: @user111222333 Indeed, but like I said the convention (and valid) way of doing custom tags is `data-{tag}`.

Comment: Please see the edits above. There is no `div` in the HTML with the custom attribute being used. It seems as if the custom attribute is added to the `div` tag, then it is added to the page. Does that seem correct?

Comment: It will probably do this, but I can't know from what you posted what is going on. Have a scour through the code after the script ran and see if you can find it.

Comment: I did that and found it. Thank you. It was an ASP.net Panel that rendered as a `div`. It was given a `tag` attribute that was evaluated server-side and the JQuery operates on that Panel. Thanks again.